# How to save an image with custom name retrieved from database in ASP.NET Core 5.0 Razor?

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload

I'm trying to save an image with the logged-in user's name.

If I set a default image name (`logo.png`) it work fine. When I try to get the name from a SQL Server database with a `foreach() {}` method, I get a null reference error.

What am I doing wrong?

My backend code:

```
[System.Obsolete]
public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToPageResult OnPostUpload(List<IFormFile> postedFiles)
{
        var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        foreach (var item in Users.Where(p => p.Id == userId))
        {
            string wwwPath = this.Environment.WebRootPath;
            string contentPath = this.Environment.ContentRootPath;

            string path = Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "usersphoto");

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }                

            List<string> uploadedFiles = new List<string>();

            foreach (IFormFile postedFile in postedFiles)
            {
              //string fileName = Path.GetFileName("logo.png");
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(item.Uname.ToString() + ".png");

                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, fileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    postedFile.CopyTo(stream);
                    uploadedFiles.Add(fileName);
                    this.Message += string.Format("<b>{0}</b> u saved correctly.<br />", fileName);
                }
            }               
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

And this is my client-side markup:

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input class="border" type="file" name="postedFiles" value="aaa" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success font-weight-bold" style="width:70px;" value="upload" asp-page-handler="Upload" />
    &ensp;
       <a asp-page="Index" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark font-weight-bold" style="width:70px;" >go back</a>
    <br/>
    <span style="color:green">@Html.Raw(Model.Message)</span>
</div>      
</form>
```

Comment: If you want to pass multiple files to action,you need to add `multiple` to input.

Comment: I want to insert just one picture for the user which will have to be saved as users name, nothing more.

Comment: When you add a breakpoint, which row you get a null reference error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that it didn't needed an foreach() cycle, but just a simple value recall from the database.

This is the final code (backend) that works for me:

```
[System.Obsolete]
    public async Task<RedirectToPageResult> OnPostUploadAsync(List<IFormFile> postedFiles)
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        NDE = await _context.Users.Where(p => p.Id == userId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        string wwwPath = this.Environment.WebRootPath;
        string contentPath = this.Environment.ContentRootPath;

        string path = Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "foto");
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        List<string> uploadedFiles = new List<string>();
        foreach (IFormFile postedFile in postedFiles)
        {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(Users.Uname.ToString() + ".png");
            
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, fileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                postedFile.CopyTo(stream);
                uploadedFiles.Add(fileName);
                this.Message += string.Format("<b>{0}</b> success.<br />", fileName);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

}